# Issue storing a byte into a register x86-64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am trying to write a function that determines the length of a string given as the first argument, so %rdi will contain char *ptr.  When I call `movb (%rdi),%rcx` to move the character pointed to by %rdi into %rcx, I get the following error:
`incorrect register '%rdx' used with 'b' suffix`
As I understand it, only certain registers can hold a byte in x86-64, so which ones can I use to move the byte into?  Or is the method I am using to extract the character at each byte in the string incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

All the general-purpose registers have the low 8 bits separately addressable as `al`, `bl`, `cl`, `dl`, `sil`, `dil`, `bpl`, `spl`, `r8b` through `r15b` (intel documentation uses `l` suffix). In addition, a few have bits 8..15 also addressable, namely `ah`, `bh`, `ch` and  `dh`.

So if you only want to load a byte, you can use one of the above. Alternatively, you can use zero- or sign-extension to widen the byte data, for example in your case `movzbl (%rdi), %ecx` (read: *move zero extended byte to long*). Note that operating on 32 bit registers zeroes the top 32 bits of the "parent" 64 bit register, but operating on 8 or 16 bit sub-registers leaves the rest of the bits unchanged.

I feel you should probably (re-)read the basic architecture section of the intel manuals.

Comment: +1, using zero/sign extensions is important, if you keep your upper bytes you create false dependencies and introduce implicit merges all over the place, this might incur quite a penalty!

Comment: it's so confusing that they use `l` suffix for single-byte register value (since naturally one would associate that with "long/double word"). 
so the reason is `l` in `al`, `bl`, ... `spl` stands for `lower`?

Comment: Exactly. It was ax, ah, al for 16 bit whole, upper byte and lower byte. I don't believe it is symmetric, for example r8h is meaningless.